# When did the 5-foot square/hex become the standard unit of measurement in Dungeons & Dragons?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, battle-map

I was playing with [AutoREALM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autorealm/) the other day and noticed a lack of a five-foot-unit of measurement. There are inches, feet, yards, meters and then fathoms (apparently, six feet). This tool seems fairly old, but the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoREALM) says it was published in 2006.

At any rate, my question is as follows - **when did the five foot square/hex become the standard unit of measurement in Dungeons and Dragons?** Or, **has it always been that?** Call me a sucker for accuracy, but I've considered switching to meters more times than just for AutoREALM measurements.